# Unable to add custom object as tab

Tags: app-development

Whenever I create a custom object without the use of wizard it doesn't appear in the list of objects to be able to add it as tab. Did I miss any step? Or should I always use the wizard?
Thanks

Comment: Can you check what you get have when you go to Setup -> Create -> Tabs and click New button in "Custom Object Tabs" section ?

Comment: @melmoussaoui Thanks!Got used to the wizard. Silly to have asked that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As told by @melmoussaoui go to Setup -> Create -> Tabs and click New button in "Custom Object Tabs" section.

Answer (score 1):

u might have reached governor limits for number of tabs in your org.

Comment: no I haven't, checked system overview !